# How do I convert the output of a bool from 1's and 0's to true or false in c

Tags: c

How to convert the output of bool in from of 1's and 0's to string say True or False.

```
float a=get_float("Give 1st side");
float b=get_float("Give 2nd side");
float c=get_float("Give 3rd side");
bool z=trcheck(a,b,c);
printf("The Triangle is %d",z);
```

Comment: Using an `if` statement or the ternary operator `...?...:...`

Comment: or an indexed array of strings

Comment: Er.... `printf("it is %s\n", z ? "true" : "false");`

Answer (score 3):

A `bool` in C is basically an integer underneath, which maps `0` to `false` and `1` to `true`¹. Using `printf("%d", z)` on that value, will give you the numerical representation.

If you want a textual representation, you will have to provide that yourself, an example would be:

```
printf("%s", z?"true":"false");
```

but there are many ways to do this.

¹ Of course, it is not that simple, check out [these](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Boolean_type) [links](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean) for more information.

Comment: I think you mean 0 to false and 1 to true.

Comment: @Rizwan you are right, I fixed it.